# Proxy error: Could not proxy request from Front End to Backend

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, proxy

*I can't data insert in the database showing this error "Proxy error: Could not proxy request /auth/login from localhost:3000 to http://127.0.0.1:8000 (ECONNREFUSED).". I have installed "http-proxy-middleware" in my client folder...*

setUpProxy.js

```
 const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    createProxyMiddleware("/auth/register", { target: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api" })
  );
};
```

Comment: Node.js can't reach your local server you specified (http://127.0.0.1:8000).

Comment: The backend local server is okay but I can't data insert in the database showing this error "proxy error: Could not proxy request /auth/login from localhost:3000 to http://127.0.0.1:8000 (ECONNREFUSED)."."

Comment: Yes, because the backend server didn't accept the location from your proxy middleware. That's exactly what ECONNREFUSED is :)

Comment: Now how do I solve it?

Comment: I can't tell you, because I don't know your backend :)